# How to swap columns in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

My intent is to allow the user to drag and drop the columns.

In form 1, there is button and when the respective button is clocked, form 2 opens with the datagridview.
Swap the column 1 with column 2 by using the mouse.
Now when you close the form2 and gain click on the button on form 1, form 2 should appear with the changed column.

What I tried?

- I tried to save the column index of the column which is moved and index of the columns with which it is swapped in columnsorder.
- I am not sure ow to carry the changed column details from child form to parent form and again parent form to child after clicking the button.

```vb
Public Class Form2
    Public ctlDataGridDirect As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

    Public columnOrder As New List(Of ColumnOrderItem)
    Public ColumnChanged As Boolean = False

    Public NotInheritable Class ColumnOrderItem
        Public Property DisplayIndex As Integer
        Public Property ColumnIndex As Integer
    End Class

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ctlDataGridDirect = Me.ctlDataGrid
        ctlDataGridDirect.ClipboardCopyMode = Windows.Forms.DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText
        With ctlDataGrid
            .AllowUserToAddRows = False
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
        End With
        ctlDataGrid.Rows.Add()
        ctlDataGrid.Rows(0).Cells("Column1").Value = Trim(0)
        ctlDataGrid.Rows(0).Cells("Column2").Value = Trim(1)
        ctlDataGrid.Rows(0).Cells("Column3").Value = Trim(2)
        ctlDataGrid.Rows(0).Cells("Column4").Value = Trim(3)
        If ColumnChanged = True Then
            For i = 0 To columnOrder.Count - 1

            Next

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ctlDataGrid_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewColumnEventArgs) Handles ctlDataGrid.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged
        ColumnChanged = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveColumnOrder(Datagridview As DataGridView)

        Dim columns As DataGridViewColumnCollection = ctlDataGrid.Columns
        For i = 0 To columns.Count - 1
            columnOrder.Add(New ColumnOrderItem With {.ColumnIndex = i, .DisplayIndex = columns(i).DisplayIndex})
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed

        SaveColumnOrder(ctlDataGrid)

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is...

1. Store the order of the column in settings. Example: 0123**54**6
2. write a routine which reorders datagrid columns as per settings data stored
3. update the settings data every time you swap column..